# WordPress database error Deadlock found

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, database-deadlocks

My website become slow due to this issue:

```
WordPress database error Deadlock found when trying to get lock;
try restarting transaction for query DELETE FROM wp_options
WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_wpseo_sitemap_cache_shop_order_%'
OR option_name LIKE '_transient_timeout_wpseo_sitemap_cache_shop_order_%'
made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), 
do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, 
do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, 
WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Gateway_COD->process_payment, 
WC_Abstract_Order->update_status, WC_Abstract_Order->add_order_note,
wp_insert_comment, wp_update_comment_count, wp_update_comment_count_now, 
clean_post_cache, clean_object_term_cache, 
do_action('clean_object_term_cache'), call_user_func_array,
wpseo_invalidate_sitemap_cache_terms, wpseo_invalidate_sitemap_cache, 
WPSEO_Utils::clear_sitemap_cache
```

Could any one tell why this happen?
How can I delete transients automatically?

Could any one phase the issue before? Is this because use of any plugin? We are using woocommerce.

Comment: Did you try using [delete_transient()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_transient)?

Comment: where i need to put this. Could you please tell , because of which reason it is happening

Comment: Well you'd need to provide the code with which you are trying to delete the transients. This is just an error what you've pasted :\